# Port scanner slow

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I've made a port scanner in C#, but I can't seem to make it go faster:

```
private void Scan()
{
    int startPort = Convert.ToInt32(txtFrom.Text);
    int endPoint = Convert.ToInt32(txtTo.Text);

    progressBar1.Value = 0;
    progressBar1.Maximum = endPoint - startPort + 1;

    for (int currPort = startPort; currPort <= endPoint; currPort++)
    {
        TcpClient tcpportScan = new TcpClient();
        tcpportScan.SendTimeout = 10;
        try
        {
            tcpportScan.Connect(txtIPaddress.Text, currPort);
            txtDisplay.AppendText("Port " + currPort + " open.\n");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            txtDisplay.AppendText("Port " + currPort + " closed.\n");
        }
        progressBar1.PerformStep();
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to speed this process up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following C# 4 code will scan the ports in parallel and notify the UI whenever one of the scans completes.

Each scan is perfomed by the ScanSinglePortTask method, which starts a scan and returns a string result with the message to display. Each task starts with the [LongRunning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions) option to notify the runtime that running a lot of tasks in parallel is OK because each operation will take a long time.

After each scan a new task that runs on the UI thread will update the messages and the progress bar, by using [TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.fromcurrentsynchronizationcontext).

The ToArray call is necessary to force enumeration of the LINQ query and start the tasks. The tasks array can be used with [Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321258) to run some other code after scanning finishes, eg. updating a busy indicator

```
    private void ScanP()
    {
        int startPort = Convert.ToInt32(txtFrom.Text);
        int endPoint = Convert.ToInt32(txtTo.Text);

        progressBar1.Value = 0;
        progressBar1.Maximum = endPoint - startPort + 1;


        var scans = from i in Enumerable.Range(startPort, 
                                               endPoint - startPort + 1)
                    select ScanSinglePortTask(i)
                        .ContinueWith(t => Report(t.Result),
                            TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
        var tasks=scans.ToArray();

    }

    private Task<string> ScanSinglePortTask(int currPort)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var tcpportScan = new TcpClient())
                    {
                        tcpportScan.SendTimeout = 10;
                        tcpportScan.Connect(txtIPaddress.Text, (int) currPort);
                    }
                    return "Port " + currPort + " open.\n";
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return "Port " + currPort + " closed.\n";
                }
            }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    }

    private void Report(object message)
    {
        txtDisplay.AppendText((string)message);
        progressBar1.PerformStep();
    }
```

Comment: This almost works perfectly :D! I've edited the code so it puts every open and closed port into a list of strings. This works perfectly, but my only problem is, the progressbar doesn't update after he found the first open port :(. Any ideas on this? Thanks!

Comment: Nice one. Do we need to call Close() after Connect() success?

Comment: No. Close() is called by TcpClient.Dispose().

Answer (score 2):

Creating connections is subject to a timeout before the request is seen as failed, which is what makes your scannig so slow. Use async code and/or multiple threads to speed things up.

Comment: Any examples on how to do this :(?

Comment: You question was if anyone knew hot to make it faster, no? ;) - ANyways, if you google for the keywords you should find what you're looking for. I'd start off with using [`Socket.BeginConnect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.beginconnect.aspx) instead of the `TcpClient` (which is a wrapper around the Socket class), that might already solve the issue.

Comment: You're welcome. Just a small hint if I may: don't try to connect to all 65535 ports in one go - more than a few (100 maybe) pending connections should be enough. Note that some firewalls may ban you (your computer or app) when they detect portscans.

Comment: Okay, but what do you mean with the ban thing actually?

Comment: A ban is typically to block all communications. If you were to try this on one of our public IPs, it would look to your scanner as if no ports were open at all after the scan has been identified.

Comment: Ooh, well all I want to do is to check for open ports to run a Minecraft server on (a game server). I hope this doesn't ban the app, because it hosts the game :(.

Comment: A SYN scan might be of interest too, although you'll end up writing ethernet frames from scratch for Windows >= XPSP2, due to restrictions on raw sockets traffic (TCP-out is prohibited).

Answer (score 0):

Try using a parallel.foreach / for loop.  This will be a lot faster.

```
    Parallel.For(0, 100, d =>
    {
        // Do processing here
        // d is the equivalent to i in a standard for loop             
    });



   List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
   Parallel.ForEach(numbers, n =>
       {
        // Do Processing here
        // n is the current item 
    });
```

Here is a link to my blog with some more detail.

http://tsells.wordpress.com/2011/03/03/using-parallel-for-and-foreach-loops-in-net-4-2/

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that the different items may (and will) be running in different threads - you'll have to properly lock your mutable data structures (like the `numbers` list in your example) and marshal to the UI thread for updating the progressbar (as in the OPs example).

Comment: @Lucero there is no need to lock numbers when using PLINQ. PLINQ partitions the data in numbers and assigns each partition to a different thread for processing.

Comment: The issue with Parallel.For/Foreach is that they aren't suited to long running tasks like network IO and will result in underutilization.